# GATE embedded Pronominal conference no class def found junit.framework.Assert

Tags: gate

While executing a Gate embedded app containing annie coreference pr I got the following error.
Gate lib was loaded using maven dependancy.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/Assert
    at gate.creole.coref.PronominalCoref.init(PronominalCoref.java:110)
    at gate.creole.coref.Coreferencer.init(Coreferencer.java:74)
    at gate.Factory.createResource(Factory.java:432)
    at gate.Factory.createResource(Factory.java:139)
    at gate.Factory.createResource(Factory.java:121)
    at com.sigmacr.OBIEPipelineBuilder.createPipeline(OBIEPipelineBuilder.java:150)

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved. The junit dependency was scoped "test". While the GATE embedded coref PR used it in runtime.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test-->should be runtime </scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting this, I've just checked in [a fix](http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/code/16993/) so in future snapshot builds non-test classes such as this one shouldn't depend on JUnit.

Comment: I'm still seeing this error on GATE v 8. What gives?